# Which Stack Exchange site is for recommendations related to programming

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have been on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) for a while.

Questions of the kind of

> recommend me some book / library / SDK / tutorial to do bla bla bla

are not allowed there.

Actually I have flagged many question of this kind as "off-topic"!

**My question is**, on which Stack Exchange site can I post this type of question and hopefully get an answer?

Comment: @NathanTuggy it is not the same, in the mentioned question, is asking about software recommendations but I am not !,  I am looking for tools [related to programming] recommendations site, this could include IDEs, libraries, SDK, etc

Comment: Those ... are software, and the linked question specifically says IDEs are fine. (Which they are, as far as I know.)

Comment: on the mentiod question, the most voted answer says: `Software Recommendations Stack Exchange accepts questions about general-purpose software, development tools and libraries, as well as more specialized software.` **but** read this,  it is copied from on-topic page of the **Software Recommendations Stack Exchange**: `note that recommendations of tutorials, data sources, media libraries (,e.g. icon collections) etc. are off-topic – as are questions like “what technology to use for …?”`,

Comment: For this not to be a duplicate (or too broad for effectively asking multiple questions) I think you need to remove "library / SDK" from it.  I think the answer for recommendations other than software ([softwarerecs.se]) and hardware ([hardwarerecs.se]) will  be to look for an SE chat room that allows them.

Comment: To begin with your list is somewhat vauge, 'bla bla bla', so nothing definite can be said. Aside from the recommendations from @PolyGeo, I think you'll find that other requests for recommendations will be generally rejected as off-topic every where. See the SE blog posts [here]( http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) for subjective questions, and [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/) for the idea that questions have answers.

Comment: @PolyGeo, Yes I guess you are right, I was not able to find a site in which these are not off-topic, chat rooms might be a good place!

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver I guess, StackExchange, is not the correct place to ask such kinds of questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> book / library / SDK / tutorial

The *only* site that comes close is [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). As the title indicates, only software is covered. Books and tutorials are off-topic almost everywhere.

Resource recommendation questions have several potential problems, and SoftwareRecs has strict quality guidelines to help weed out the bad questions that are difficult to answer. Please be sure to read their help center and look up existing questions for examples of both good and bad questions before asking your own.

Comment: Strictly speaking books and tutorials are not (yet) considered off-topic everywhere e.g. http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3660 but I have upvoted your answer because I think that they should be.

Comment: @PolyGeo thanks, I was not aware of that.